# What are the steps to create a Currency detection app for Android?

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition

I am new to image processing and good at android programming. I am interested to develop a currency detection app. Can anyone please mention each step in detail for developing a currency detection app for Android?

Comment: check opencv in android

Comment: check this url : http://assistech.iitd.ernet.in/mobile-currency-identification-for-vi.php, http://www.slideshare.net/karthik0101/counterfeit-currency-detection , https://prezi.com/ozhxdbgacxdd/android-application-to-detect-fake-currency/

Comment: Thanks Amee Joshi. They are really helpful